# Thank you letter export to Word - maintaining fonts

Tags: civicontribute, export

CiviCRM 5.7.6, WordPress 5

My client has a message template for thank-you letters (contribution) that utilizes Google Fonts. The fonts export and render perfectly in PDF, but do not work in the Word export file (which is what the client really needs).  Is there a particular trick to using these fonts such that they will translate into Word?  (I also tried the OpenOffice format, which lost *all* formatting, not just the fonts.)

Thanks in advance.